# convert java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to capture and store image in high quality and upload as high quality using kotlin. i cant find any examples in kotlin but found one in java but want to convert it to kotlin so it can work with my application.

```
public void clickFoto(View view) {
        takePic();
    }
```

//takePic()

```
 private void takePic() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        *File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/your_name_folder/a" + "/photo_" + timeStamp + ".png");*
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
    }
```

//onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                            imgFoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                            imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
```

// getRealPathFromUri

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: If you have intelliJ IDE installed, create a kotlin project or file and paste the java code in the kotlin file, intelliJ will ask you if it should convert it to kotlin, select yes. The Java source will be converted to kotlin

Answer (score 0):

you can find convert Java to Kotlin file menu in Android Studio (Ctrl + Shift + Alt+ K).

and anyway, using converting, your code will be like this.

```
fun clickFoto(view:View) {
  takePic()
}

private fun takePic() {
  val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
  val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/your_name_folder/a" + "/photo_" + timeStamp + ".png")
  imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
  val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT)
}


fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent) {
  when (requestCode) {
    PICTURE_RESULT -> if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
      try
      {
        val thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
          getContentResolver(), imageUri)
        imgFoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri)
      }
      catch (e:Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }
}

fun getRealPathFromURI(contentUri:Uri):String {
  val proj = arrayOf<String>(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
  val cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
  val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
  cursor.moveToFirst()
  return cursor.getString(column_index)
}
```